# Error writing react test: By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

When running my react test, I get the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/test/dev/pm/client/node_modules/spacetime/src/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import Spacetime from './spacetime.js'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       6 | import search from '../../assets/images/search.svg';
       7 | import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
    >  8 | import spacetime from "spacetime";
         | ^
       9 | import languages from "../../libraries/languages/language-list";
      10 | import _ from "lodash";
      11 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Mentor/MentorList.js:8:1)
```

Here's my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Here's the test

```
import MentorList from "../MentorList";
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

const setup = (props = {}) => {
    return sallow(<MentorList {...props} />);
}

describe("MentorList", () => {
    it("renders without error", () => {
        const wrapper = setup();
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Heres my jest.config.js

```
    const esModules = ['spacetime'].join('|');

    module.exports = {
        // ...
        transform: {
            [`(${esModules}).+\\.js$`]: 'babel-jest',
            '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js',
            "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
            // ...
        },
        transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
        // ...
    };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It says what's wrong. See the line with transformIgnorePatterns

Comment: @EstusFlask I updated the question.